# Spark Highly Controlled Aggregate

Tags: scala, apache-spark, signal-processing, fft, distributed-computing

I am currently working on implementing the radix-2 version of the Cooley–Tukey Fast Fourier Transform Algorithm on Apache Spark 2.2. If you're not familiar with how the algorithm works, all you really need to know for the sake of my question is that it requires breaking a vector down into a perfect binary tree structure then combining each pair of leaves into a new vector (much like merge sort but with complex math). I would like to accomplish this in Spark using the .treeAggregate function.

The issue is, within each partition aggregate the combine/sequence ops do not take into account the perfect ordering the FFT algorithm requires. For example, if I have a vector of size 8 I am passing through the algorithm, my algorithm needs to be processed in this order (each number representing the index of the value in the original vector):

```
               0  4  2  8  1  5  3  7
                \ /  \ /   \  /  \  /
                0,4  2,8    1,5   3,7
                  \   /      \     /
                 0,2,4,8     1,3,5,7
                     \          /
                    0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

However, aggregate may do this in any order and may not even necessarily combine vectors of equal size. So how do I:

1. Make the aggregate function how I need to within the partitions?
2. Then make treeAggregate function how I need it to when combining the partitions?

You can assume a power of 2 number of partitions of equal size. The original vector size is a power of 2 as well. I've thought of maybe not doing this with just treeAggregate and using mapPartitions then calling aggregate on each partition so they all have a single vector, then calling treeAggregate on that. That may give a little more control but still doesn't solve my problem. Other than that I am at a loss.

EDIT: I realize the merge-sort analogy and tree may be mis-leading. To clarify, those values in that tree above must be in that EXACT ordering. The positioning within the vector is a major part of this algorithm.

Comment: This is too broad and it's more a "why my code isn't working?" kind a question without code. Please read about how to ask question on SO https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ! For the time being I'm voting to close the question.

Comment: Its a question on how Spark functions. It requires a very specific knowledge of the language. I could add code but that would be useless since as I've already explained using the API in a standard way won't work.